# No overlapping timestamp with condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

currently to stop overlapping timestamps of specific `event_type` in following table:

```
    CREATE TABLE foo (
        id                    UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        event_type            TEXT,
        from                  timestamp WITH time zone NOT NULL,
        to                    timestamp WITH time zone NOT NULL,
        deleted               timestamp WITH time zone DEFAULT NULL
    );
```

i'm using:

```
    ALTER TABLE foo
        ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlapping_times_for_event_type EXCLUDE
        USING gist (event_type WITH =, tstzrange(from, to, '[)') WITH &&);
```

Above works fine.

**Question:**

How do i make it so that the constraint does not kick in if the `foo` had `deleted`
value populated? so that i can create delete one and create a new one with same dates without the constraint stopping me. 
I only want it to stop user from creating overlapping timerange entries of same `event_type` only if they're not `deleted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `WHERE` clause to the constraint, making it a partial one. It will be checked only for row that have `deleted IS NULL`. Rows that have `deleted` populated will be completely ignored by the constraint checks:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ADD CONSTRAINT no_overlapping_times_for_event_type EXCLUDE
    USING gist (event_type WITH =, tstzrange("from", "to", '[)') WITH &&)
    WHERE (deleted IS NULL) ;
```

Comment: `from` and `to` are reserved keywords. I suggest you use some other names for these columns (eg. `ts_from, ts_to`) if you aren't already doing so.

Comment: oh yes that works! what a boss. cheers mate